# How to change index in Persistant navigation bar in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigation

I am using this package. Package Name : https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar
but the problem is it works fine i use bottom nav bar but when I try to navigate using another buttons it does not change the bottom selected element.

I searched on the google but it did not work. I read the documentation too but nothing found useful . i used the navigation code was provided by the package or the package author. but that too not worked.

````
import 'dart:core';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:newmart/OTP/landing_page.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Order/transaction_history.dart';
import 'package:newmart/mpin/set_mpin.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent_tab_view.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'package:newmart/Company/about_us.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Company/contactus.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Company/privacypolicy.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Company/termcondition.dart';
import 'package:newmart/mpin/mpin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Screens/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:newmart/mpin/mpinservices.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';

class DrawerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DrawerWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<DrawerWidget> createState() => _DrawerState();
}

class _DrawerState extends State<DrawerWidget> {
  String? name;
  String? mobileNo;
  String? walletBalance;
  bool loadingData = true;
  forgetmpin() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String mobileNumber = prefs.getString("mobileNumber").toString();
    Mpinservices.forgetmpin(mobileNumber).then((response) {});
  }

  late PersistentTabController controller;

  late PersistentTabController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
   
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          PersistentTabView(
            controller: _controller,
            items: [
              PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                title: 'Home',
              ),
              PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                title: 'Search',
              ),
            ],
            onItemSelected: (index) {
              // Do something when a tab is selected.
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

    ```

================
````

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Order/order.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Screens/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Recharge/recharge.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Company/support.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:newmart/mpin/set_mpin.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent_tab_view.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key, required this.mobileNumber});
  final String mobileNumber;
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
        title: ("Home"),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined),
        title: ("Order"),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.wallet),
        title: ("Wallet"),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.charging_station),
        title: ("Recharge"),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.support_agent),
        title: ("Support"),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
    ];
  }

  final controller = PersistentTabController();
  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      const DashboardScreen(),
      const Order(),
      const SetMpin(),
      const Recharge(),
      const Support(),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PersistentTabView(
      context,
      controller: controller,
      screens: _buildScreens(),
      items: _navBarsItems(),
      confineInSafeArea: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white, // Default is Colors.white.
      handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, // Default is true.
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      stateManagement: true,
      hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
      decoration: NavBarDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
      ),
      popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
      popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,

      navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style1,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because PersistentBottomNavBar only listens to changes made to the bottom navigation bar itself. If you want to change the selected tab when you navigate to a new screen using another button, you need to call the updateSelectedTab method on the PersistentTabController. For example:

```dart
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent_bottom_nav_bar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  PersistentTabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PersistentBottomNavBar(
      controller: _controller,
      items: [
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: 'Home',
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          title: 'Search',
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          title: 'Settings',
        ),
      ],
      onItemSelected: (index) {
        // Do something when a tab is selected.
      },
    );
  }

  void navigateToSearch() {
    // This will navigate to the Search screen.
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/search');

    // This will update the selected tab to the Search tab.
    _controller.updateSelectedTab(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: sir, how can I use this in drawer widget. which is in side a seperate folder. I tried creating new instance of PersistentTabController _controller; but it tells updateSelectedTab is not defined.

Comment: please give me little code snippet sir.

Comment: controller and items are not defined. I get this error in vss code sir...I have updated my question sir and added drawer code.

Comment: Okay, Please replace PersistentBottomNavBar() with PersistentTabView().

Comment: No sir. I tried that too but not working. sorry for the late reply.